# Saving large map in GenServer, is this a valid use case?

Tags: elixir, gen-server

Could this be a valid use for GenServer:

If the process_id is the user_id and it is unique. Process contains a query result of a big map of data which is generated via DB. Now if 100's of users log in to the system and ask for their data map they all are saved in their own process referenced by the user_id which is unique

So upon asking for the map I will check to see if there is a process with user_id ( which is process id ) and grab it and feed it to back to the user, if not then I create it and put it in a new state

now if user updated his map, at the update, I make sure to update the sate or create a new one.

Thank you for your guidance

Comment: `Elixir` provides [`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html#content) module for this purpose, but I never use it because plain old good `GenServer` is IMHO a cleaner concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perfectly valid unless you have a million users logged in. This is usually handled in Erlang ecosystem with so-called *pools*.

The main principle is: you limit the size of the pool of processes to, say, 100 (5000, whatever, it mostly depends on your HW capacity) and use any preemptive storage for newcomers (the oldest dies if the capacity is over the limit.)

You might consider serializing these displaced data, or spawn new nodes, or whatever. In general, the process holding the state is the preferable solution in OTP, unless you hit the memory limit. In this case you’d probably opt-in for some persistent storage, like DETS or (better) [mnesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnesia).

It worth noting that Elixir provides [`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html#content) module for this purpose, but I never use it because plain old good GenServer is IMHO a cleaner concept.

Comment: what do you mean by "size of the pool of processes to, say, 100 " are you referring to the number of processors? This is a big application and there are other processes running at different part of the applications. Are we talking about the total? Sorry I am a bit confused now.

Comment: What I was saying is “there must be a limit put on a pool size.” The exact number is to be found experimentally, basing on your setup.

Comment: your advice would be the same if there is a list to be saved in the state, a list as `list(Strinnt.t())` where string values can be more than 10000x?

Answer (score 1):

If your genserver does nothing else than storing a map and returning it via an API, maybe it's not worth creating a lot of processes.

You can merely use an ets table for this purpose or use the Agent module (key=user id, value=map).

Comment: Creating a lot of erlang processes in incredibly cheap, while lookup a huge map is not. This is a wrong advice.

Comment: I do not believe that map lookup is expensive.

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned it on somewhere on [Elixir forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/when-are-agent-and-task-supervisor-useful/896) already - for pure state store use Agent, for pure computation use Task - for everything in between - GenServers! ;)

Even if you do not need any computation at the moment it may appear that you will need it soon and just because of this I would stick to GenServer.

Comment: The link to the main page of Elixir forum makes no sense. Please provide a valid reference.

Comment: The link is there just to mention the forum and link it. I will try to google the post a bit later.